# How to remove (delete) the unsaved changes in an existing angularjs form when clicked on cancel button or edit icon

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**1.** the scenario is that there are multiple forms in the page and

**2.** when a user fills in the input fields in one of the form and doesn't save them, those changes should be deleted as soon as they close the current form by the cancel button on the close icon.

**3.** if there is any previous data in the input fields that data should be unaltered 
and if there is any additional data written to it and not saved should be deleted

**HTML:**

```
 <md-content class="md-padding no-margin">
    <div>
        <form name="formone" novalidate ng-submit="saveData(profile)">
            <div id="basicDetails">
                <div layout="row" layout-align="space- center">
                    <p class="uc-heading">Basic Details</p>
                    <i ng-if="!condition" class="fa-times fa" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="toggleEditPanel('details')"></i>
                </div>
                <div >
                    <label>First name</label>
                    <input ng-model="profile.details" name="details" ng-required="true" />
                    <label>Last name</label>
                    <input ng-model="profile.details.data.data" name="details[[data]]" ng-required="true" />
                </div>
                <div flex layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                    <md-button ng-if="!condition" class="md-raised md-custom-button" ng-click="toggleEditPanel('details')">Cancel</md-button>
                    <md-button type="submit" ng-disabled="profileForm.$invalid" class="md-raised md-custom-button" ></md-button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</md-content>
```

Comment: Wait, so when he cancels, it deletes the data, but the data should remain unaltered ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two things to your controller:

1. On init, save the current value of `profile.details` and `profile.details.data.data`.
2. Adde a method `resotreData()` to your controller where you reassing the saved values to `profile.details` and `profile.details.data.data`.

And then add `resotreData()` to the ng-click event of your cancel button.